# Why Swift Tuples can be compared only when the number of elements is less than or equal to 6?

Tags: swift, tuples, swift5

I read in [HackingWithSwift](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/how-to-compare-two-tuples-for-equality) that Swift tuples can be compared with `==` operator only when the number of elements is less than or equal to 6. What is the reason behind this limitation ?

Comment: See the related methods, but because it's currently the max implemented: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1541073 There is a need to declare them, so Apple stopped at 6.

Comment: "The proposed arity here is 6, which is large enough for most reasonable tuples (but not as large as I'd prefer), without having massive code increase" 
https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0015-tuple-comparison-operators.md

Comment: Thank you @Larme for clarifying my doubt :-)

Comment: Thank you @koropok for clarifying my doubt :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### Background: Tuples aren't `Equatable`

Swift's tuples aren't `Equatable`, and they actually can't be (for now). It's impossible to write something like:

```swift
extension (T1, T2): Equatable { // Invalid
    // ...
}
```

This is because Swift's tuples are *structural types*: Their identity is derived from their structure. Your `(Int, String)` is the same as my `(Int, String)`.

You can contrast this from *nominal types*, whose identity is solely based off their name (well, and the name of the module that defines them), and whose structure is irrelevant. An `enum E1 { case a, b }` is different from an `enum E2 { case a, b }`, despite being structurally equivalent.

In Swift, only nominal types can conform to protocols (like `Equatble`), which precludes tuples from being able to participate.

#### ...but `==` operators exist

Despite this, `==` operators for comparing tuples are provided by the standard library. (But remember, since there is still no conformance to `Equatable`, you can't pass a tuple to a function where an Equatable type is expected, e.g. `func f<T: Equatable>(input: T)`.)

One `==` operator has to be manually be defined for every tuple arity, like:

```swift
public func == <A: Equatable, B: Equatable,                                                       >(lhs: (A,B        ), rhs: (A,B        )) -> Bool { ... }
public func == <A: Equatable, B: Equatable, C: Equatable,                                         >(lhs: (A,B,C      ), rhs: (A,B,C      )) -> Bool { ... }
public func == <A: Equatable, B: Equatable, C: Equatable, D: Equatable,                           >(lhs: (A,B,C,D    ), rhs: (A,B,C,D    )) -> Bool { ... }
public func == <A: Equatable, B: Equatable, C: Equatable, D: Equatable, E: Equatable,             >(lhs: (A,B,C,D,E  ), rhs: (A,B,C,D,E  )) -> Bool { ... }
public func == <A: Equatable, B: Equatable, C: Equatable, D: Equatable, E: Equatable, F: Equatable>(lhs: (A,B,C,D,E,F), rhs: (A,B,C,D,E,F)) -> Bool { ... }
```

Of course, this would be really tedious to write-out by hand. Instead, it's written using [GYB](https://nshipster.com/swift-gyb/) ("Generate your Boilerplate"), a light-weight Python templating tool. It allows the library authors to implement `==` using just:

```swift
% for arity in range(2,7):
%   typeParams = [chr(ord("A") + i) for i in range(arity)]
%   tupleT = "({})".format(",".join(typeParams))
%   equatableTypeParams = ", ".join(["{}: Equatable".format(c) for c in typeParams])

// ...

@inlinable // trivial-implementation
public func == <${equatableTypeParams}>(lhs: ${tupleT}, rhs: ${tupleT}) -> Bool {
  guard lhs.0 == rhs.0 else { return false }
  /*tail*/ return (
    ${", ".join("lhs.{}".format(i) for i in range(1, arity))}
  ) == (
    ${", ".join("rhs.{}".format(i) for i in range(1, arity))}
  )
}
```

Which then gets expanded out by GYB to:

```swift
@inlinable // trivial-implementation
public func == <A: Equatable, B: Equatable>(lhs: (A,B), rhs: (A,B)) -> Bool {
  guard lhs.0 == rhs.0 else { return false }
  /*tail*/ return (
    lhs.1
  ) == (
    rhs.1
  )
}

@inlinable // trivial-implementation
public func == <A: Equatable, B: Equatable, C: Equatable>(lhs: (A,B,C), rhs: (A,B,C)) -> Bool {
  guard lhs.0 == rhs.0 else { return false }
  /*tail*/ return (
    lhs.1, lhs.2
  ) == (
    rhs.1, rhs.2
  )
}

@inlinable // trivial-implementation
public func == <A: Equatable, B: Equatable, C: Equatable, D: Equatable>(lhs: (A,B,C,D), rhs: (A,B,C,D)) -> Bool {
  guard lhs.0 == rhs.0 else { return false }
  /*tail*/ return (
    lhs.1, lhs.2, lhs.3
  ) == (
    rhs.1, rhs.2, rhs.3
  )
}

@inlinable // trivial-implementation
public func == <A: Equatable, B: Equatable, C: Equatable, D: Equatable, E: Equatable>(lhs: (A,B,C,D,E), rhs: (A,B,C,D,E)) -> Bool {
  guard lhs.0 == rhs.0 else { return false }
  /*tail*/ return (
    lhs.1, lhs.2, lhs.3, lhs.4
  ) == (
    rhs.1, rhs.2, rhs.3, rhs.4
  )
}

@inlinable // trivial-implementation
public func == <A: Equatable, B: Equatable, C: Equatable, D: Equatable, E: Equatable, F: Equatable>(lhs: (A,B,C,D,E,F), rhs: (A,B,C,D,E,F)) -> Bool {
  guard lhs.0 == rhs.0 else { return false }
  /*tail*/ return (
    lhs.1, lhs.2, lhs.3, lhs.4, lhs.5
  ) == (
    rhs.1, rhs.2, rhs.3, rhs.4, rhs.5
  )
}
```

Even though they automated this boilerplate and could theoretically change `for arity in range(2,7):` to `for arity in range(2,999):`, there is still a cost: All of these implementations have to be compiled and produce machine code that ends up bloating the standard library. Thus, there's still a need for a cutoff. The library authors chose 6, though I don't know how they settled on that number in particular.

#### Future

There's two ways this might improve in the future:

1. There is a Swift Evolution pitch (not yet implemented, so there's no official proposal yet) to introduce [Variadic generics](https://forums.swift.org/t/variadic-generics/54511), which explicitly mentions this as one of the motivating examples:

   > Finally, tuples have always held a special place in the Swift language, but working with arbitrary tuples remains a challenge today. In particular, there is no way to extend tuples, and so clients like the Swift Standard Library must take a similarly boilerplate-heavy approach and define special overloads at each arity for the comparison operators. There, the Standard Library chooses to artificially limit its overload set to tuples of length between 2 and 7, with each additional overload placing ever more strain on the type checker. Of particular note: This proposal lays the ground work for non-nominal conformances, but syntax for such conformances are out of scope.

   This proposed language feature would allow one to write:

   ```swift
   public func == <T...>(lhs: T..., rhs: T...) where T: Equatable -> Bool { 
       for (l, r) in zip(lhs, rhs) {
           guard l == r else { return false }
       }
       return true
   }
   ```

   Which would be a general-purpose `==` operator that can handle tuples or any arity.
2. There is also interest in potentially supporting [non-nominal conformances](https://forums.swift.org/t/variadic-generics/54511#non-nominal-conformances-21), allowing structural types like Tuples to conform to protocols (like `Equatable`).

   That would allow one to something like:

   ```swift
   extension<T...> (T...): Equatable where T: Equatable {
       public static func == (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool { 
           for (l, r) in zip(lhs, rhs) {
               guard l == r else { return false }
           }
           return true
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you for providing such a detailed explanation :-)