# Do tuples conform to Comparable?

Tags: swift, tuples, max, comparable, comparison-operators

Tuples in Swift seem to conform to `Comparable` inasmuch as I get these results:

```
print ( (3,0) < (2,10000) ) // false
print ( (0,0,5) < (0,0,7) ) // true
```

It seems to do a left-right member-by-member comparison of the tuples: it compares the first tuple members against each other, then the 2nd, and so on, until it finds a pair that are nonequal, and returns whether the first member of that pair is less than the second. Very sensible.

It even works with tuples that contain multiple types, as long as they are comparable, and as long as the two tuples being compared are of the same type:

```
print( ("a",4) < ("b",3) ) // true
```

So why does this give an error?

```
print ( [(1,2),(0,2)].max() )   ⛔️ Type '(Int, Int)' cannot conform to 'Comparable'
```

Thinking that maybe it would help if I declared the types explicitly, I tried:

```
typealias IntPair = (Int,Int)

let a: IntPair = (0,1)
let b: IntPair = (0,2)
let array: [IntPair] = [a,b]
print(array.max())   ⛔️ Type '(Int, Int)' cannot conform to 'Comparable'
```

My only conclusion is that the static function `<` is defined on tuples of the same type, whose components are all `Comparable`, but those tuples nonetheless do not conform to `Comparable`. But that doesn't seem very likely.

Does anyone know why `max()` does not work on arrays of tuples of the same type whose arguments are all `Comparable`?

Comment: Check out [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72155017/3141234) on a related question. It's about `Equatable`/`==`, but it's much the same.

Comment: You would need to do something like shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29736377/2303865)

Comment: [SequenceAlgorithms.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/SequenceAlgorithms.swift)

Comment: `extension Sequence { public func max<T: Comparable, U: Comparable>() -> Element? where Element == (T, U) { self.max(by: <) } }
`

Answer (score 3):

> My only conclusion is that the static function < is defined on tuples of the same type, whose components are all Comparable, but those tuples nonetheless do not conform to Comparable.

This is exactly the case here.

The operators for tuples are declared in [Tuple.swift.gyb](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/Tuple.swift.gyb). Here is an excerpt:

```
%   comparableTypeParams = ", ".join(["{}: Comparable".format(c) for c in typeParams])
%   for op, phrase in comparableOperators:
/// Returns a Boolean value indicating whether the first tuple is ordered
/// ${phrase} the second in a lexicographical ordering.
...
@inlinable // trivial-implementation
public func ${op} <${comparableTypeParams}>(lhs: ${tupleT}, rhs: ${tupleT}) -> Bool {
  if lhs.0 != rhs.0 { return lhs.0 ${op} rhs.0 }
  /*tail*/ return (
    ${", ".join("lhs.{}".format(i) for i in range(1, arity))}
  ) ${op} (
    ${", ".join("rhs.{}".format(i) for i in range(1, arity))}
  )
}
%   end
```

It is not possible to conform tuples to `Comparable` because that would require the compiler to generate a *protocol witness* for the comparison operators This protocol witness is what would be called when you call a protocol requirement "through the protocol", e.g.

```
func f<T; Comparable>(x: T, y: T) {
    print(x < y) // here it would call the protocol witness of the "<" in the metadata of T
}
```

Alternatively, allow extensions on tuples and add a `Comparable` extension on tuples to the standard library. Either way, this would require changes to the compiler, and probably outweighs the benefit of having `Comparable` tuples.

If you want to use `max` on an array of tuples, you can just pass the operator to the `by:` parameter:

```
[(1, 2), (3, 4)].max(by: <)
```

Answer (score 2):

Nope! Only nominal ("named") types can conform to protocols, which excludes tuples.

The standard library just happens to define `<` operators for tuples up to 6 elements.

Comment: Well, I realized that's why _I_ couldn't make it conform, but I never assume that just because I can't do it, there isn't another way to do it based on inner workings that I don't know about. (For instance, the fact that an optional is really an Enum makes some things possible that one wouldn't otherwise realize…) Thanks.